# Change figure size and figure format in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib

I  want to obtain fig1 exactly of 4 by 3 inch sized, and in tiff format correcting the program below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list1 = [3,4,5,6,9,12]
list2 = [8,12,14,15,17,20]

plt.plot(list1, list2)
plt.savefig('fig1.png', dpi = 300)
plt.close()
```

Comment: Does changing the extension in the file name from .png into .tif create the real tiff image?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can set the figure size if you explicitly create the figure with

```
plt.figure(figsize=(3,4))
```

You need to set figure size before calling `plt.plot()`
To change the format of the saved figure just change the extension in the file name. However, I don't know if any of matplotlib backends support tiff

Comment: Does changing the extension in the file name from .png into .tif create the real tiff image?

Comment: As I wrote, I don't know, but from the comments on the other answer it seems that tiff is non supported

Comment: Keep in mind `plt.figure(figsize=(3,4))` needs to be called before calling `plt.plot()`

Answer (score 65):

You can change the size of the plot by adding this before you create the figure.

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [16,9]
```

Comment: This is just what I needed to use in Jupyter Notebook to make the plot wider.

Comment: Working in jupyter notebooks

Comment: rcParams has enormous power of customizability

Comment: I used this and my image got stretched, matplotlib did not adjusted the content for the new aspect ratio. However if I do not save but show the plot on a window, it works. Any clues on that?

Comment: Pl. use some other aspect ratios (like: 4,3) and update me.

Comment: thanks, increasing `rcParams['figure.dpi']` made it even better

Comment: This really helped me, but I'm having trouble finding documentation on how rcParams actually works.

Answer (score 26):

The first part (setting the output size explictly) isn't too hard:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
list1 = [3,4,5,6,9,12]
list2 = [8,12,14,15,17,20]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(list1, list2)
fig.savefig('fig1.png', dpi = 300)
fig.close()
```

But after a quick google search on matplotlib + tiff, I'm not convinced that matplotlib can make `tiff` plots.  There is some mention of the [GDK backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) being able to do it.

One option would be to convert the output with a tool like imagemagick's `convert`.

(Another option is to wait around here until a [real matplotlib expert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325565/joe-kington) shows up and proves me wrong ;-)

Comment: If you have the [GDK backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) installed you can use it to draw tiffs natively.  There may be some dependencies you have to install.

Comment: @GWW -- I saw that mentioned, but I also saw [this thread](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/16bit-tiff-support-td11448.html) implying that is a lie.  Of course, it's an old thread, so it may have been fixed since then.

Answer (score 24):

If you need to change the figure size **after** you have created it, use the methods

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figheight(value_height)
fig.set_figwidth(value_width)
```

where `value_height` and `value_width` are in inches. For me this is the most practical way.

Comment: This is increasing only the figure, not the window containing it.

Comment: matplotlib has one of the worst APIs ever, the trouble is, it is the only easiest to learn tool in python.